# how to get selected value of data list by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get selected value of data list by j query.I want to set a value on data list by j `query`.
  I had use this to select a value through javascript

```
 $('#departmentIdcc option[value='+departiddd+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `.val()` method like `$('#departmentIdcc').val(departiddd);` to get value `$('#departmentIdcc').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected value of a `select` element using `val()`:

```
var selectedValue = $('#departmentIdcc').val();
```

Also note that you should use `val()` to *set* the selected value too:

```
$('#departmentIdcc').val(departiddd);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `val()` option

To get the value `var option=$('#departmentIdcc').val();`

To set value `$('#departmentIdcc').val(departiddd);`

Comment: Note that the OP is trying to *get* the value.

Comment: actually i want to set a value from javascript to datalist.

Comment: @user3906140 did you checked console log